# On a subclass of kernel functions

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, functional-analysis, analysis, positive-definite

Let $\mathcal{X}$ be a nonempty set.

A symmetric function $K: \mathcal{X} \times \mathcal{X} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is called a kernel on $\mathcal{X}$ if $$\sum_{i=1}^{n} \sum_{j=1}^{n} c_{i} c_{j} K\left(x_{i}, x_{j}\right) \geq 0$$
holds for any $x_{1}, \ldots, x_{n} \in \mathcal{X}, c_{1}, \ldots, c_{n} \in \mathbb{R} \text {, given } n \in \mathbb{N}$.

Common examples of kernels defined on Euclidean space $\mathbb{R}^{d}$ include:

- Linear kernel: $K(\mathbf{x}, \mathbf{y})=\mathbf{x}^{T} \mathbf{y}, \quad \mathbf{x}, \mathbf{y} \in \mathbb{R}^{d}$.
- Polynomial kernel: $K(\mathbf{x}, \mathbf{y})=\left(\mathbf{x}^{T} \mathbf{y}+r\right)^{n}, \quad \mathbf{x}, \mathbf{y} \in \mathbb{R}^{d}, r \geq 0, n \geq 1$
- Gaussian kernel: $K(\mathbf{x}, \mathbf{y})=e^{-\frac{\|\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{y}\|^{2}}{2 \sigma^{2}}}, \quad \mathbf{x}, \mathbf{y} \in \mathbb{R}^{d}, \sigma>0$.
- Laplacian kernel: $K(\mathbf{x}, \mathbf{y})=e^{-\alpha\|\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{y}\|}, \quad \mathbf{x}, \mathbf{y} \in \mathbb{R}^{d}, \alpha>0 .$

Let $d=1$. I am interested in kernels that can be written as $K(x,y)=f_1(\min(x,y))f_2(\max(x,y))$ for some functions $f_1,f_2$. In the examples I gave, the linear and the Laplacian kernels satisfy this property.

What are some other kernels that satisfy this property? Can we identify this subclass in a nice way?

Answer (score 1):

These kernels are called "factorizable kernels" in the book [Reproducing Kernel Hilbert Spaces in Probability and Statistics.](https://books.google.ch/books?id=bX3TBwAAQBAJ)

In Chapter 7 Section 3 they derive necessary and sufficient conditions on the functions $f_1$ and $f_2$ for such a $K$ to be a kernel. Up to technical difficulties in handling zeros this boils down to $\frac {f_1} {f_2}$ being real, positive and non-decreasing.

Furthermore they give an example of a non-factorizable kernel.